# iOS - Generate and play indefinite, simple audio (sine wave)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio

I'm looking to build an incredibly simple application for iOS with a button that starts and stops an audio signal.  The signal is just going to be a sine wave, and it's going to check my model (an instance variable for the volume) throughout its playback and change its volume accordingly.

My difficulty has to do with the indefinite nature of the task.  I understand how to build tables, fill them with data, respond to button presses, and so on; however, when it comes to just having something continue on indefinitely (in this case, a sound), I'm a little stuck!  Any pointers would be terrific!

Thanks for reading.

Comment: It may be that AVAudioPlayer is what I need to get started...

Comment: AVAudioPlayer would be the route to go if you're just looking to play a pre-made sound file of a sine wave (you'll be able to control the volume but nothing else, such as the frequency).

Answer (score 17):

Here's a bare-bones application which will play a generated frequency on-demand. You haven't specified whether to do iOS or OSX, so I've gone for OSX since it's slightly simpler (no messing with Audio Session Categories). If you need iOS, you'll be able to find out the missing bits by looking into Audio Session Category basics and swapping the Default Output audio unit for the RemoteIO audio unit.

Note that the intention of this is purely to demonstrate some Core Audio / Audio Unit basics. You'll probably want to look into the `AUGraph` API if you want to start getting more complex than this (also in the interest of providing a clean example, I'm not doing any error checking. **Always** do error checking when dealing with Core Audio).

You'll need to add the `AudioToolbox` and `AudioUnit` frameworks to your project to use this code.

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface SWAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    AudioUnit outputUnit;
    double renderPhase;
}
@end

@implementation SWAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
//  First, we need to establish which Audio Unit we want.

//  We start with its description, which is:
    AudioComponentDescription outputUnitDescription = {
        .componentType         = kAudioUnitType_Output,
        .componentSubType      = kAudioUnitSubType_DefaultOutput,
        .componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple
    };

//  Next, we get the first (and only) component corresponding to that description
    AudioComponent outputComponent = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &outputUnitDescription);

//  Now we can create an instance of that component, which will create an
//  instance of the Audio Unit we're looking for (the default output)
    AudioComponentInstanceNew(outputComponent, &outputUnit);
    AudioUnitInitialize(outputUnit);

//  Next we'll tell the output unit what format our generated audio will
//  be in. Generally speaking, you'll want to stick to sane formats, since
//  the output unit won't accept every single possible stream format.
//  Here, we're specifying floating point samples with a sample rate of
//  44100 Hz in mono (i.e. 1 channel)
    AudioStreamBasicDescription ASBD = {
        .mSampleRate       = 44100,
        .mFormatID         = kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
        .mFormatFlags      = kAudioFormatFlagsNativeFloatPacked,
        .mChannelsPerFrame = 1,
        .mFramesPerPacket  = 1,
        .mBitsPerChannel   = sizeof(Float32) * 8,
        .mBytesPerPacket   = sizeof(Float32),
        .mBytesPerFrame    = sizeof(Float32)
    };

    AudioUnitSetProperty(outputUnit,
                         kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                         kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                         0,
                         &ASBD,
                         sizeof(ASBD));

//  Next step is to tell our output unit which function we'd like it
//  to call to get audio samples. We'll also pass in a context pointer,
//  which can be a pointer to anything you need to maintain state between
//  render callbacks. We only need to point to a double which represents
//  the current phase of the sine wave we're creating.
    AURenderCallbackStruct callbackInfo = {
        .inputProc       = SineWaveRenderCallback,
        .inputProcRefCon = &renderPhase
    };

    AudioUnitSetProperty(outputUnit,
                         kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
                         kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                         0,
                         &callbackInfo,
                         sizeof(callbackInfo));

//  Here we're telling the output unit to start requesting audio samples
//  from our render callback. This is the line of code that starts actually
//  sending audio to your speakers.
    AudioOutputUnitStart(outputUnit);
}

// This is our render callback. It will be called very frequently for short
// buffers of audio (512 samples per call on my machine).
OSStatus SineWaveRenderCallback(void * inRefCon,
                                AudioUnitRenderActionFlags * ioActionFlags,
                                const AudioTimeStamp * inTimeStamp,
                                UInt32 inBusNumber,
                                UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                                AudioBufferList * ioData)
{
    // inRefCon is the context pointer we passed in earlier when setting the render callback
    double currentPhase = *((double *)inRefCon);
    // ioData is where we're supposed to put the audio samples we've created
    Float32 * outputBuffer = (Float32 *)ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;
    const double frequency = 440.;
    const double phaseStep = (frequency / 44100.) * (M_PI * 2.);

    for(int i = 0; i < inNumberFrames; i++) {
        outputBuffer[i] = sin(currentPhase);
        currentPhase += phaseStep;
    }

    // If we were doing stereo (or more), this would copy our sine wave samples
    // to all of the remaining channels
    for(int i = 1; i < ioData->mNumberBuffers; i++) {
        memcpy(ioData->mBuffers[i].mData, outputBuffer, ioData->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize);
    }

    // writing the current phase back to inRefCon so we can use it on the next call
    *((double *)inRefCon) = currentPhase;
    return noErr;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    AudioOutputUnitStop(outputUnit);
    AudioUnitUninitialize(outputUnit);
    AudioComponentInstanceDispose(outputUnit);
}

@end
```

You can call `AudioOutputUnitStart()` and `AudioOutputUnitStop()` at will to start/stop producing audio. If you want to dynamically change the frequency, you can pass in a pointer to a `struct` containing both the renderPhase double and another one representing the frequency you want.

Be careful in the render callback. It's called from a realtime thread (not from the same thread as your main run loop). Render callbacks are subject to some fairly strict time requirements, which means that there's many things you Should Not Do in your callback, such as:

- Allocate memory
- Wait on a mutex
- Read from a file on disk
- Objective-C messaging (Yes, seriously.)

Note that this is not the only way to do this. I've only demonstrated it this way since you've  tagged this core-audio. If you don't need to change the frequency you can just use the `AVAudioPlayer` with a pre-made sound file containing your sine wave.

There's also [Novocaine](https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine), which hides a lot of this verbosity from you. You could also look into the Audio Queue API, which works fairly similar to the Core Audio sample I wrote but decouples you from the hardware a little more (i.e. it's less strict about how you behave in your render callback).

Comment: Thanks very much for this!  I had put "iOS" in the question's title, but sorry, I should have added a tag and/or a note in the question body.  I'll fix this now.

Comment: @Rogare good point, I missed that! My goal, really, was just to demonstrate some of the concepts at play in Core Audio, such that you can get started. That is to say : you will almost certainly have more questions later if you start digging into this :p. Good luck!

Comment: how about generate a on signal or off signal ?

Comment: @RajuGujarati do you mean being able to switch between generating two different tones? You could make the context (`inputProcRefCon`) a struct containing information about the sine wave you want to create. For example, you could have a float specifying the frequency to render, and then change that float from within your app.

Comment: Hey, I am working with some similar code but the only difference is that my phase step is:

phaseStep = (2*M_PI)/ ((double)kSampleRate);
time += phaseStep;
 
Then, the sine wave is calculated as:

y = sinf(time * frequency);

The problem is that, doing this, I get a distorted sine wave at frequencies above 8k (like with a second tone of lower intensity). I would like to share the phase among other tones and that's why I am doing this. If I do just as what you do, it works perfectly.
What can it be?

Comment: @leo2_uru sounds like it could be an aliasing problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing#Sampling_sinusoidal_functions , you may also want to make sure you're using `double` throughout the rendering process instead of `float` (though Float32 output is fine)